# alternative to import/export sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, migration, site-collection, site

I am trying to export a site with subsites to a new site collection but because I am using hundred of custom features, lists, master pages & relative sharepoint things, I am getting many expection while importing, **Looking for a alternative that will just export/import a site without validating anything**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't so much validation as it is basic SharePoint functionality.  Custom Features and such can create any number of custom entities and if those entities do not exist on the site you are attempting to import it into, then it cannot be imported - by definition.  The import/export process does not know how to create the entities, only how to use them.  If you want to import the site elsewhere then you will need to deploy the custom features there as well.  This is especially true of features that create Site Columns, Content Types.

If you are looking for some data-only migration then you may have to export everything to Excel/Explorer and than manually import it into the destination.

Comment: if I am migrating a site to a new site collection which is being created in the same web application, do I have to install all features, master page and other things ?
Cheers

Comment: I thought site collections share things like features, master pages, n that

Comment: That all depends on how the features themselves were scoped but the features will have to be installed *and* activated before it will allow an import